# Setting PayPal header text dynamically?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am doing paypal integration in my website in a section called stores where the user can sell his products from my store. And i am storing the paypal accounts of my sellers to pay him directly when customer purchase something from his store in my website. Is there any PayPal variable like **cpp_header_image**(which is used for sending image as a header) to send text which should be shown in checkout page.

**Note:** The seller email id i'm passing will not be mine(Since each sellers will have their own Paypal Business email id)?

Comment: i think you need to have "PayPal Premier accounts" for this

Comment: @swapnesh: Since `cpp_header_image` is there for showing image, i think there should be some similar way to show text there. But i could not able find that

Comment: @Mr.Stranger any luck with getting the text?